# What exactly is this list that you see of 'Installed Products' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio when you click on About-->Help you get a popup box which shows a list of Installed Products. What can we call the items in this list by? I want to understand exact technical name. Can we call it a list of 'Visual Studio Plugins'? Or can we call them list of 'Visual Studio extensions'? Even extension is doubtful because some of these are actually labelled as extensions,but that is exception.

Obviously it is not a list of 'products' even though that appears to be the title. If that was the case even Microsoft Office should be appearing here.

If these are really products -- is it like 'product' within the context of Visual Studio, something like that?

Note: I know there was similar question already asked and someone might forward me to that and close this question. But please know that that question was specifically about the meaning of numbers appearing in front of these items and not about the items themselves.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that Visual Studio is an IDE an Integrated Development Environment. Which means that it takes a bunch of programs and groups them together in a convenient way for development. What you see in that list is all the installed products that pertains to development from Visual-Studio's perspective, including version numbers and serial numbers.

Comment: So going back to the same question -- what are these items in that list technically called? Purely from system manual point of view.

Comment: "Installed products". I understand your issue but you have to think from the perspective of an IDE.

Comment: If they are really products, I should be able to find them out from Windows search bar. E.g. Word or Excel. So obviously they are not simply 'products'. They maybe products within the context of Visual Studio -- but then I never heard the term like 'Visual Studio Products', they might be referred to as something else (like plugin or something) I am sure. Sorry I am not satisfied with this answer. Thanks though.